# Ошибка при работу с Xgboost: must be real number, not str

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

Помогите пжл. 
Обучаю Xgboost на Time Series.
Вот мой код:

Считываем данные

```
data = pd.read_csv('../Portfolio/DJIA.csv', 
                            index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
data.head(3)
```

Создаем признаки на основании даты

```
def create_features(df):
    """
    Creates time series features from datetime index
    """
    df['date'] = df.index
    df['dayofweek'] = df['date'].dt.dayofweek
    df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.quarter
    df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
    df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
    df['dayofyear'] = df['date'].dt.dayofyear
    df['dayofmonth'] = df['date'].dt.day
    df['weekofyear'] = df['date'].dt.weekofyear

    X = df[['dayofweek','quarter','month','year',
           'dayofyear','dayofmonth','weekofyear']]
    return X

X, y = create_features(data), data['DJIA']
```

Применяем функцию к данным:

```
X, y = create_features(data), data['DJIA']
```

Обучаем бустинг

```
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
reg.fit(X, y)
```

После обучения выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-296-02a8ae37993a> in <module>
      1 reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
----> 2 reg.fit(X, y)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, callbacks)
    358                                    missing=self.missing, nthread=self.n_jobs)
    359         else:
--> 360             trainDmatrix = DMatrix(X, label=y, missing=self.missing, nthread=self.n_jobs)
    361 
    362         evals_result = {}

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in __init__(self, data, label, missing, weight, silent, feature_names, feature_types, nthread)
    417                 self.set_label_npy2d(label)
    418             else:
--> 419                 self.set_label(label)
    420         if weight is not None:
    421             if isinstance(weight, np.ndarray):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in set_label(self, label)
    669             The label information to be set into DMatrix
    670         """
--> 671         self.set_float_info('label', label)
    672 
    673     def set_label_npy2d(self, label):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in set_float_info(self, field, data)
    590             self.set_float_info_npy2d(field, data)
    591             return
--> 592         c_data = c_array(ctypes.c_float, data)
    593         _check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixSetFloatInfo(self.handle,
    594                                                c_str(field),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in c_array(ctype, values)
    215     if isinstance(values, np.ndarray) and values.dtype.itemsize == ctypes.sizeof(ctype):
    216         return (ctype * len(values)).from_buffer_copy(values)
--> 217     return (ctype * len(values))(*values)
    218 
    219 

TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Я понимаю, что ошибка скорее всего в том, что на вход обучения мы подаем дату вместо цыфр. Пытался изменить значения фрейма с помощью float(), но ошибка не пропадает. 
Как это исправить? 
Спасибо за помощь)

Дополнительные данные:
Команда 1:

```
X.iloc[0]
```

Результат:

```
dayofweek        3
quarter          3
month            7
year          2009
dayofyear      204
dayofmonth      23
weekofyear      30
Name: 2009-07-23 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

Команда 2:

```
X.dtypes
```

Результат:

```
dayofweek     int64
quarter       int64
month         int64
year          int64
dayofyear     int64
dayofmonth    int64
weekofyear    int64
dtype: object
```

Команда 3:

```
y.iloc[0]
```

Результат:

```
'9069.29'
```

Команда 4:

```
y.dtypes
```

Результат:

```
dtype('O')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, дело в фрейме `y`, который имеет строковый тип.

Попробуйте так:

```
X, y = create_features(data), data['DJIA'].astype(float)
```

Comment: спасибо большое ) В общем, проблема была в том, что в Датафлейме были значения ".". по этому и возникала ошибка. Ваш код помог понять это)

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(data['DJIA'], errors="coerce")` - надежнее будет ;)